# Up to date NVIDIA vs ATI list

Tags: graphics-card, performance, comparison

It used to be simple... there were 4 NVIDIA cards and 4 other cards (long long ago :p)
But today both NVIDIA and ATI have so many graphic cards at the same time it's near enough impossible to compare them.

Does anybody know of an up to date list which puts ATI and NVIDIA in comparison?

Not just a comparison of their top products but really all their current cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[The Desktop Graphics Card Comparison Guide](http://www.techarp.com/showarticle.aspx?artno=88&pgno=0)** is currently covering **409 desktop graphics cards**, this comprehensive comparison will allow you to easily **compare 20 different specifications for each and every card**. *(last updated: December 2009)*

For Notebooks please refer to the **[The Mobile GPU Comparison Guide](http://www.techarp.com/showarticle.aspx?artno=98&pgno=0)**

For Business class graphics cards see the **[The Workstation Graphics Card Comparison Guide](http://www.techarp.com/showarticle.aspx?artno=95&pgno=0)**

Answer (score 1):

My favourite source for comparison of this sort of thing is [Toms Hardware GPU charts](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/charts/graphics-cards,1.html). They have a variety of benchmarks from different applications and games so you can compare fully what is best at what.

Other than this, your best bet is Wikipedia ([Nvidia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce) / [ATI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATI_Technologies) click on series and see a full list.) and the official [ATI](http://www.ati.com) and [Nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com) sites and then manually compare the specification.